# Queries with Objectify: UmbrellaException

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I am using Objectify to manage GAE Datastore for my GWT app. The problem is that I am not using queries properly and I get UmbrellaExceptions as per below:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Server Error: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Number
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.Receiver.onFailure(Receiver.java:44)
```

Say that I have a class `Box` with a unique field `String id`. I want to get the Box object whose `id == "cHVQP6zZiUjM"`

This is how I do it now:

```
public Box getBox(String boxId)
{
    Objectify ofy = ObjectifyService.begin();
    Query<Box> q=ofy.query(Box.class).filter("id",boxId);
    Box targetBox = q.get();

    return targetBox;
}


@Entity
public class Box extends DatastoreObject{
    private String id;
    private String title;
}
```

I tried doing this with ofy.load() but that method is not defined in my class Objectify (I don't know why).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer:  You are missing the @Id annotation in your entity.

The long answer:  Id fields are special in the datastore.  The id is not a real property, but rather a part of the Key that identifies the entity.  You can't really filter on id fields, but you can filter on a special field called `__key__`.  Objectify is somewhat clever about letting you filter by the id field and converting this to a `__key__` filter under the covers, but it can't do it if you don't annotate the entity properly!

Actually I'm a little confused because Objectify shouldn't let you register the entity without an @Id field.

By the way, there are two sections of the documentation:  Objectify4 (release coming soon) and Objectify3.  Since you're using Ofy3, there is no load() method.

Another thing:  Get-by-key operations are strongly preferred to queries when the operations are equivalent (as they are in your example).

Answer (score 2):

Your key is encoded. Try using:

```
 Box targetBox = ofy.get(Box.class, KeyFactory.stringToKey(boxId));
```

To decode your key.

Comment: Actually "id" is not the datastore key. Just a different field that is unique. What should I do in this case?

Comment: Hey. Just changed the method as I have seen on Google Code but still not working with "filter". New error message as per above. Thanks

Comment: You have to use `@Id` or `@Index` in your fields to put them in the index of the datastore. Only indexed properties can be queried. You can follow [this example](https://github.com/stickfigure/motomapia/blob/master/java/com/motomapia/entity/Person.java).

Comment: You have to Index a field to filter a field. So add @Index before your field in your Entity.java .